# ggplot histogram as a percent of a specific group

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R, and have created some simple histograms of a categorical independent variable vs the dependent variable. All facet wrapped according to the categories.

In this case I am using sensitive data, so cannot share any data.

**Code**

```
ggplot(merged, aes(CV)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~BUILDING_AGE, ncol = 2) +
  labs(title = "BUILDING_AGE vs CV", y = "Co-efficient of variation", x = "BUILDING_AGE")
```

Where CV = coefficient of variation (continuous dependent variable) and BUILDING_AGE is the age of the buildings (categorical independent variable - with 7 categories/groups 1-7)

**The problem**

The problem is that some of the categories have only a small amount of data relative to the other categories, so when I plot the histogram I cannot see the histogram and distribution of the data in these groups with smaller amounts of data.

Ie: the y-axis (counts) is scaled far too large for the categories with very low counts.

**Question**

Is there a way that each of the facet wrapped windows y-axis could be rescaled according to each of the categories they are displaying?

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `'free'` to the `scales` parameter of `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()`, this should address your problem:

`facet_wrap(~BUILDING_AGE, ncol = 2, scales = 'free')`

Further reading:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.0.0/topics/facet_wrap

Comment: likely the correct solution. Just make sure to subtitle or caption the title noting the free scales.